# Complex JSON structure and databinding in NativeScript ListView

Tags: json, typescript, nativescript, radlistview

I have an interesting data set being returned from an API and I can't resolve the binding in the NativeScript listview for an object of objects within the parent binding context. The listview `items` (feeditems) is an ObservableArray(). Everything is working fine I'm just stumped on repeating the `feeds` object (which could have more than one item) in the `styles` object which is accessible and the other items accessing the parent bindingContext work fine.

```xml
<lv:RadListView items="{{ feedItems }}">
        <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
            <GridLayout rows="auto, *, auto" columns="70, *, auto" class="feed-item">
              <!-- Title and Description -->
                <Label text="{{ title }}" color="{{ $parents['RadListView'].styles[site_id]['entry_title_color'], $parents['RadListView'].styles[site_id]['entry_title_color'] }}" />
              <Label text="&#xf397;" color="{{ $parents['RadListView'].styles[site_id]['entry_btn_color'], $parents['RadListView'].styles[site_id]['entry_btn_color'] }}" />
              <!-- Feed Image -->
                  <Image src="{{ image }}" stretch="aspectFit" />
              <!-- Details Row -->


              <!-- STUCK HERE TRYING TO REPEAT THE 'FEEDS' OBJECT -->
                <Repeater items="{{ $parents['RadListView'].styles[site_id]['feeds'], $parents['RadListView'].styles[site_id]['feeds']  }}">
                  <Repeater.itemTemplate>
                    <Label text="{{ icon }}" />
                  </Repeater.itemTemplate>
                </Repeater>


                <Label text="{{ friendlytime }}" />
            </GridLayout>
        </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
      </lv:RadListView>
```

Here is a sample of the `styles` JSON binded:

```
{"2":
   {"id":2,"name":"TEST","icon":"https://www.TEST.com/test.png",
"entry_title_color":"#f00","entry_text_primary_color":"#3AF",
"feeds":
    {"2":
        {"id":2,"type":"rss","icon":"","notify":1}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: On a side note: it is not recommended to use a 'Repeater' in the 'itemTemplate' of the RadListView. That is element is a slow performance-wise component and it might interfere with the RadListView built-in virtualization and make the performance not good. Think of it like this, when the native cell element for an itemTemplate is being created it will need to wait for the 'Repeater' to create its elements which are not virtualized and that creation process is relatively slow thus breaking the built-in virtualization or worsening it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see 'site_id' defined in the styles JSON. So probably just skipping the '[site_id]' part would be enough.

And one off-topic: please remove the **StackLayouts** you don't need them.

Comment: Thanks @HHristov - I removed a bunch of other layout code so the inner StackLayout is wrapping a few other things :) Just forgot to remove here. I'll check back on the `site_id` but that part is working on the other bindings to the `$parents...` so I'm thinking it's necessary for the data model. It's driving me crazy but might have it working soon. Thanks for the reply and I'll be sure to update with the full answer once solved.